# Gradle jacoco coverage report with more than one submodule(s)?

Tags: java, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

Does anybody know how to configure a gradle file for java jacoco report
that contain codecoverage of more than one gradle submodule?

my current approach only shows codecoverage of the current submodule but not
codecoverage of a sibling-submodul.

I have this project structure

```
- build.gradle (1)
- corelib/
    - build.gradle (2)
    - src/main/java/package/Core.java
- extlib/
    - build.gradle (3)
    - src/main/java/package/Ext.java
    - src/test/java/package/Integrationtest.java
```

when i execute `gradlew :extlib:check :extlib:jacocoTestReport` the junit-test "Integrationtest.java"
is executed and a codecoverage report is generated that does not contain codecoverage for corelib classes like Core.java

The result should include the codecoverage of Ext.java and Core.java

I already read

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html
- and [Filter JaCoCo coverage reports with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887805/filter-jacoco-coverage-reports-with-gradle)

but found no clues

here is content of the gradle files

```
// root build.gradle (1)
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
// common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

```
// build.gradle (2) subproject build file for corelib.
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

dependencies {
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
    }
}
```

---

```
// build.gradle (3) subproject build file for extlib.
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

dependencies {
    compile project(':corelib')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'

    // this does not compile
    // jacocoTestReport project(':pixymeta-core-lib')
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
    }
}

// workaround because android-studio does not make the test resources available
// see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64887#c13
task copyTestResources(type: Copy) {
    from sourceSets.test.resources
    into sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
}
processTestResources.dependsOn copyTestResources
```

---

[Update 2016-08-01]

thanks to @Benjamin Muschko i also tried in the root gradle file

```
// https://discuss.gradle.org/t/merge-jacoco-coverage-reports-for-multiproject-setups/12100/6
// https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoMerge.html
task jacocoMerge(type: JacocoMerge) {
   subprojects.each { subproject ->
      executionData subproject.tasks.withType(Test)
   } 

}
```

but got error message (with gradle-2.14)

```
* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':jacocoMerge'.
> No value has been specified for property 'jacocoClasspath'.
> No value has been specified for property 'executionData'.
> No value has been specified for property 'destinationFile'.
```

---

there is also the gradle plugin https://github.com/paveldudka/JacocoEverywhere where i have asked for mulit-submodule support https://github.com/paveldudka/JacocoEverywhere/issues/16

[update 2016-08-01] i found a working solution based on https://github.com/palantir/gradle-jacoco-coverage

See my own answer below

Comment: Has anybody experience with [gradle-3.4+-jacoco-coverage](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-jacoco-coverage) if the new verify feature allows jacoco coverage report over more than one submodules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me

```
plugins {
    id 'org.kordamp.gradle.jacoco' version '0.43.0'
}

config {
    coverage {
        jacoco {
            enabled
            aggregateExecFile
            aggregateReportHtmlFile
            aggregateReportXmlFile
            additionalSourceDirs
            additionalClassDirs
        }
    }
}
```

https://kordamp.org/kordamp-gradle-plugins/#_org_kordamp_gradle_jacoco

Comment: This plugin was long overdue and has made my setup much simpler! Note to viewers, the syntax has slightly changed from the above, so check latest documentation

Comment: @aarbor thanks for that, I've made the changes to reflect latest version

Answer (score 9):

Finally I found this plugin: https://github.com/palantir/gradle-jacoco-coverage that did the job for me:

root gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // see https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'

        // https://github.com/palantir/gradle-jacoco-coverage
        classpath 'com.palantir:jacoco-coverage:0.4.0'      
    }
}

// https://github.com/palantir/gradle-jacoco-coverage
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.jacoco-full-report'
```

all subprojects that has

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

are included in the report.

[Update 2023-07-20]

Now there is a new gradle plugin that does the job. Therefore i changed the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. So far seems to be working well, but I have one issue: for some reason is not working for my app module. Did it happen to you? How did you configure the app module? I applied the jacoco plugin but it won't appear in the report. Thanks

Comment: According to the `README`, this plugin seems to be _considered obsolete as of Gradle 3.4_.

Comment: but from gradle 6+ some of the JacocoReport properties are read only like additionalClassDirs, additionalSourceDirs, classDirectories, executionData ect. So in gradle 6+ it wont work. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html#N24096

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (with some sonar specific parts):

```
def getJacocoMergeTask(Project proj){
    def jmClosure =  {
        doFirst {
            logger.info "${path} started"
            executionData.each { ed ->
                logger.info "${path} data: ${ed}"
            }
        }
        onlyIf {
            executionData != null && !executionData.isEmpty()
        }
    }

    def jacocoMerge = null
    if(!proj.tasks.findByName('jacocoMerge')){

        jacocoMerge = proj.tasks.create('jacocoMerge', JacocoMerge.class)
        jacocoMerge.configure jmClosure

        // sonar specific part
        proj.rootProject.tasks["sonarqube"].mustRunAfter jacocoMerge

        proj.sonarqube {
            properties {
                property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", jacocoMerge.destinationFile.absolutePath
            }
        }
        // end of sonar specific part

        logger.info "${jacocoMerge.path} created"
    } else {
        jacocoMerge = proj.tasks["jacocoMerge"]
    }
    jacocoMerge
}


afterEvaluate { project ->
    def jacocoMerge = getJacocoMergeTask(project)

    project.tasks.withType(Test) { task ->
        logger.info "${jacocoMerge.path} cfg: ${task.path}"

        task.finalizedBy jacocoMerge
        jacocoMerge.dependsOn task

        task.doLast {
            logger.info "${jacocoMerge.path} executionData ${task.path}"
            jacocoMerge.executionData task
        }

        def cfg = configurations.getByName("${task.name}Runtime")
        logger.info "${project.path} process config: ${cfg.name}"

        cfg.getAllDependencies().withType(ProjectDependency.class).each { pd ->
            def depProj = pd.dependencyProject
            logger.info "${task.path} dependsOn ${depProj.path}"
            def jm = getJacocoMergeTask(depProj)

            task.finalizedBy jm
            jm.dependsOn task

            task.doLast {
                logger.info "${jm.path} executionData ${task.path}"
                jm.executionData task
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will merge all the executionData from all the projects, that used a certain project during testing as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new task of type [JacocoMerge](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoMerge.html) that aggregates the JaCoCo reports from all subprojects. See a similar discussion in this [post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/merge-jacoco-coverage-reports-for-multiproject-setups/12100/6).

Comment: In my case also JaCoCo works for app module, but not for all the other lib modules. After adding a task jacocoMerge(type: JacocoMerge){} to my app level build gradle, how can I trigger this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a merged report without merged `exec` file. Create a new task to the root of `build.gradle` with following content.

```
task jacocoReport(type: JacocoReport) {
    for (p in allprojects) {
        def testTask = p.tasks.findByName("test")
        if (testTask != null)
            dependsOn(testTask)

        executionData.setFrom(file("${p.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"))
        classDirectories.from(file("${p.buildDir}/classes/java/main"))
    }
}
```